# Can custom code be run along side the OS on Allwinner A20?

Tags: soc

My design utilises a programable AttTiny to manage things like events on the main PMIC, handle resets on the wifi and bluetooth etc, and the status LEDs, I wanted to communicate with the main CPU from the AttTiny, I've written firmware but I am aware that the Allwinner A20 is just a SoC, but It does have quite a lot of useful IO, just after the best way to run a bit of firmware on it, I know I can provide Operating systems that start a C/ruby/etc script that can use the IO, but thats a lot of hassle.

I would like to run the code on the SOC its self and not in the operating system, as I would like to allow the user to run what ever operating system they want, and not have to download a bunch of scripts for the computer to work correctly.

By on it, I mean on the chip its self, not ruby/python/etc scripts in the operating system.

Comment: This is very unclear, you write that you know how to run an operating system and write C code to do what you want, and you write that you have written firmware, but you're asking.. exactly what are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS is running "on the SoC itself" - the SoC has a CPU which processes whatever code it is instructed to. The OS has a bootloader and kernel which loads itself into the CPUs address space and starts it running on the CPU.

If you want your stuff to be run as well, you need to either write your own bootloader/kernel to run your code and then sequence loading the OS (basically like loading a virtual machine), or much more simply accept that the OS makers have already done the hard work of getting their OS to share CPU time with programs running on it.

The easiest way in which to do this is to have the OS load your code. It can be done with any program you integrate into the OS - be that user mode software (e.g. Python/Ruby script interpreter), or a kernel mode driver.

You appear to be trying to do something low-level to help the OS run on the hardware. That is the exact purpose of drivers - to help the OS code interact with its host hardware. So you need to write drivers for your hardware that "anyone wanting to run what ever OS they want" will be able to install.

If you think about it, any hardware you install in a computer requires a driver (be it distributed with the OS itself, or installed separately). "People" are perfectly used to installing drivers for hardware they are working with (e.g. Graphics Card drivers), or downloading OS distributions specifically for a given hardware (e.g. Raspbian for the RasPi). You either need to release a driver to be installed to the OS, or release distributions specifically for your hardware.